# How to store 2bit , 1 bit, 1 bit and four bit value in one byte integer

Tags: c

I am new to storing this type of values. I have few values for header field. 
2bit = 2 , 1bit = 1, 1 bit = 0, 4bit = 13. How can I store it in uint8 in the order? Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   uint8_t m;
   uint8_t one, two, three, four;
   one = 2;
   two = 1;
   three = 1;
   four = 13;

   // do not know how to store, 

   //assuming m is stored
   one = (m >> 7) & 1;
   two = (m >> 5) & 3;
   three = (m >> 4) & 1;
   four = m & 15;
   printf("first %i , second %i, third %i, four %i", one, two, three, four);
   return 0
}
```

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already know how to retrieve the stored value using bit shifting. Reverse it to store values.

```
m = ((one & 1) << 7) | ((two & 3) << 5) | ((three & 1) << 4) | (four & 15);
```

This code is based on your code: `one` is 1-bit, `two` is 2-bit, `three` is 1-bit and `four` is 4-bit wide. `2` is assigned to `one`, so it will be treated as zero by `& 1`.

If you want to assign 2 bits to `one` and 1 bit to `two`, use this for storing:

```
m = ((one & 3) << 6) | ((two & 1) << 5) | ((three & 1) << 4) | (four & 15);
```

and this for retrieving:

```
one = (m >> 6) & 3;
two = (m >> 5) & 1;
three = (m >> 4) & 1;
four = m & 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of Bitlayout(memorylayout) will be useful.

```
typedef struct
{
  UINT32  unOne     :  2;
  UINT32  unTwo     :  1;
  UINT32  unThree   :  1;
  UINT32  unFour    :  4;
} MType;
```

...

```
MType       DummyMMsg;
```

...

```
DummyMMsg.unOne = 2;
DummyMMsg.unTwo = 1;
DummyMMsg.unThree = 0;
DummyMMsg.unFour = 13;
```